# Changing baseSeries dynamicilly

Tags: highcharts

I want to make a chart with 4 series' and show only 1 or 2 of them at the same time. The user can choose, which series he wants to see. This works fine with series.show and series.hide, but the baseSeries, set in "navigator", doesn't change.

Is there a way to change it dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigator series is based on first series data, as a result is not updated. In case when you would like to update navigator series, you need to use setData() on series[1] object.

http://jsfiddle.net/sbochan/HwuRr/

```
chart.series[1].setData([5,2,1,2,4,6,10]);
```